# Android Time SLots

Tags: android, user-interface, datepicker

I have this method for binding time slots in my `RecyclerView` in my app, but I want something else

```
private ArrayList<String> getTimeSet() {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
       Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
       calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, i);
       String day = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
       results.add(i, day);
    }
    return results;
}
```

[image]

this is the result of the above lines of code

But i want something like this with a change that the app does not take the previous time from the current one,,,for eg if it is 4 o clock then the time slots must start from 4 o clock onwards,,Suggest me guys
[image]

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your method. Please check with this one.
Just pass the boolean value to check whether the day is current day or not.

```
private ArrayList<String> getTimeSet(boolean isCurrentDay) {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        if(!isCurrentDay)
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, i);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        String day1 = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        String day2 = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        String day = day1 + " - " + day2;
        results.add(i, day);
    }
    return results;
}
```

**OR**

You can use this method to get the time slots for next day. But, it will be better if you pass you current date boolean value to above method and check whether date is for Today or Next Day.

```
private ArrayList<String> getNextDayTimeSet() {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9); //Added this line only
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, i);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        String day1 = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        String day2 = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        String day = day1 + " - " + day2;
        results.add(i, day);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: yes it works,,but for todays date only,,,I want is when i select todays date,,it displays time slots next to current time but hen i select tomorrow's date it must display time slots from the very begining as in my screenshot

Comment: @neha I have modified the answer.

Comment: @shubham,,,this modified mthd binds time slots from the start i.e 9 am but i i select todays date it must bind it from current time,,I want both the cases to work

Answer (score 0):

I have created a class for generating the time slots and date slots. Try the code,

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author Neeraj
 */
public class DateSlotClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> dateList = getDataSet();
        System.out.println(dateList);
        for (String string : dateList) {
            System.out.println(getTimeSet(string));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates the time slots based on the date provided
     *
     * @param dateString the chosen date
     * @return list of times
     */
    private static ArrayList<String> getTimeSet(String dateString) {
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat inSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE : dd-MMM");
            Date inDate = inSdf.parse(dateString);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(inDate);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR) + 1);

            if (!isTodaysDate(cal)) {
                cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            }

            results = new ArrayList<>();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                String time1 = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
                String time2 = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                String day = time1 + " - " + time2;
                results.add(i, day);
            }
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Test if the given date is today
     *
     * @param input the chosen date
     * @return true if date is todays
     */
    private static boolean isTodaysDate(Calendar input) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        String inString = sdf.format(input.getTime());

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        String todayString = sdf.format(today.getTime());

        return inString.equals(todayString);
    }

    /**
     * Generates the date slots based on the date provided
     *
     * @param dateString the chosen date
     * @return list of dates
     */
    private static ArrayList<String> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList<String>();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE : dd-MMM");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            String day = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
            results.add(i, day);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```